# Prove that if $A\subseteq B$ then $B^C\subseteq A^C$ for any set $C$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, set-theory, examples-counterexamples

**Definition**

A set $R$ is a (binary) relation if any its element is a ordered pair, that is $z\in R$ if and only if there exist $x$ and $y$ such that $z=(x,y)$. In particular if $R$ is contained in the cartesian product of two set $A$ and $B$ we say that $R$ is a relation of between $A$ and $B$ and if $B$ is equal to $A$ we say that $R$ is a relation in $A$.

**Definition**

If $R$ is a relation we call domain of $R$ that set whose elements are a first coordinate of some pair of the relation, that is
$$
\text{dom}\,R:=\{x:\exists\,y\,\text{such that}\,(x,y)\in R\}
$$
and analogously the range of $R$ is that set whose elements are the second coordinate of the relation, that is
$$
\text{rank}\,R:=\{y:\exists\,x\,\text{such that}\,(x,y)\in R\}
$$

So it is possible to prove that the above two defined set exist using the $ZFC$'s formalism but this now has not matter so we proceed to give the following well know definition.

**Definition**

A function $f$ is a relation such that if $(x,y)$ and $(x,z)$ are such that $(x,y),(x,z)\in f$ then $y=z$.

**Definition**

Let $A$ and $B$ sets. So the set whose element are functions from $A$ to $B$ is denoted by the symbol $B^A$.

Again it is possible to prove that the above defined set exist using $ZFC$'s formalism but now this again has not matter.

So with the previous definition I ask explain if it is true that the inclusion
$$
A\subseteq B
$$
implies the inclusion
$$
B^C\subseteq A^C
$$
for any other set $C$ as it seems Munkres stated. So could someone help me, please?

Comment: What you’re calling the rank of $R$ is actually the *range* of $R$. Plainly the result is false: if $A=\varnothing\ne B$, and $C=\{1\}$, $B^C\ne\varnothing$, but $A^C=\varnothing$. The inclusion goes the other way: $A^C\subseteq B^C$.

Comment: Oh yeah! I edit immediately the question!

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Okay so if $A\neq\emptyset$ then $A^C\subseteq B^C$, right? Could you prove it, please?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Anyway could be that $C^A\subseteq B^C$? and if $A,B\neq\emptyset$ could be that the original inclusion is true?

Comment: It’s true for $A=\varnothing$, too. If $f\in A^C$, then $f\subseteq C\times A\subseteq C\times B$, so $f\in B^C$, since it satisfies the defining condition for a function. \\ $C^A\subseteq B^C$ iff $A=C\subseteq B$.

Comment: So substantially  if $A\subseteq B$ then always $A^C\subseteq B^C$, right?

Comment: Yes; that inclusion is genuinely trivial when you look at the definitions.

Comment: Okay, indeed if $A\subseteq B$ and $A,B\neq\emptyset$ then generally it is not true that $C^A\subseteq C^B$ or $C^B\subseteq C^A$, right?

Comment: A function from $A$ to $C$ must have domain $A$, and a function from $B$ to $C$ must have domain $B$, so a function from $A$ to $C$ can be a function from $B$ to $C$ if and only if $A=B$.

Comment: Okay, all clear. Thanks too much for your assistance.

Comment: You’re welcome.

Comment: Might I ask where this question came from. Because sometimes for a set $X$, $X^C$ means the relative complement of $X$ in some larger set $U$ which we choose based on context and assume all sets we're dealing with to be subsets of. And in this sense, if $A\subseteq B$ then it is true that $B^C\subseteq A^C$.